# Routing packets between two nics on the same system

Tags: routing

I have a small network setup with a ubuntu router that has two nics.
enp2s0 is used to set up a network with vlans, enp3s0 connects to a different local network.

```
enp3s0 ip 192.168.53.203/26
enp2s0 ip 192.168.8.1/24
```

i have a switch set up at 192.168.8.239/24

How do i get to estabish a connection between my two nics so i can access the switch's web interface from the other local network.

Comment: Do you have appropriate routes set on the computers of the "other local network"? They need to have a route entry to `192.168.8.0/24` network.

Comment: Do i need it? its directly connected to enp3s0

Comment: Yes, the other computers in `192.168.53.203/26` network need to know how to reach the `192.168.8.0/24` network. Those computers are not directly connected to `enp3s0`.

Answer (score 0):

To enable routing with Linux, "IP forward" has to be (permanently) enabled. IP forwarding is, in simple words, the ability to accept incoming network packets on one interface, recognize that it is not meant for the system itself, and forward it accordingly.

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and search for the following lines:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Or do it with your terminal in one line:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Just make sure that your router has (working) interfaces in all your networks.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i have it enabled.

Comment: The you are done. User your router as gateway or `route` destination, as long as the machine does have interfaces in the destination networks (and your targets know the route back to them) `ip_forward` will take care of everything.

Comment: Well i cant seem to get a ping from enp2s to enp3s nor reach it from outside the router...

Comment: When an interface isn't responding to ping (on the same network), something other than ip_forward is going wrong.

Comment: I get a "Destination Host Unreachable" message.
And i can see both interfaces sending out echo requests but thats about it.

Comment: *Where* do you see "Destination Unreachable" and *where* do you see outgoing echo requests? If those are on the target network, triple check your route back.

Comment: PING 192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1) from 192.168.53.203 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.53.203 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable


Correction, they are ARP Requests

Comment: Wen ARP is not successful, solve the cause, You will most likely have a layer 2 problem.